# What is meaning of "::" syntax in Laravel Blade (Ex: @include('googletagmanager::head') )?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I used Laravel Package: [spatie/laravel-googletagmanager](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-googletagmanage) , in my view included view include some view of package

```
 @include('googletagmanager::head')
```

What is meaning of `::` syntax ?
Where can I find reference document about it ?
When `ScriptViewCreator` is called ( `vendor/spatie/laravel-googletagmanager/src/ScriptViewCreator.php` ) ?

Thank you!

Comment: From the [documentation on views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#views)_

"_Package views are referenced using the package::view syntax convention._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`googletagmanager` is a package you probably installed, and `head` is one of the views involved in this package. By using `@include('googletagmanager::head')` you poiny to the `head` view in the `googletagmanager` package. This works as well in the `view()` function which you usually used in a controller.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#views